# Attribute Error When Pandas and Multiprocessing Modules Are Both Used

Tags: python, pandas, multiprocessing

I am fairly new to Python and am building an application that queries a database in a background process and then sticks the results in a pandas dataset for some analysis. I can get the analysis and querying sections working fine independently; however, when I combine my code I get the following error (which keeps repeating until I kill the program):

```
'module' object has no attribute 'day_abbr'
'module' object has no attribute 'day_abbr'
'module' object has no attribute 'day_abbr'
'module' object has no attribute 'day_abbr'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\z083423\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 380, in main
    prepare(preparation_data)
  File "C:\Users\z083423\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 495, in prepare
    '__parents_main__', file, path_name, etc
  File "G:\Stress Test\PPNR Models\Model_Management_App\Model_Mgnt_Proj\ModelMgntMainDeleteThis.py", line 5, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "C:\Users\z083423\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import hashtable, tslib, lib
  File "tslib.pyx", line 3744, in init pandas.tslib (pandas\tslib.c:66221)
  File "tslib.pyx", line 3662, in pandas.tslib.TimeRE.__init__ (pandas\tslib.c:53412)
  File "tslib.pyx", line 3545, in pandas.tslib.LocaleTime.__init__ (pandas\tslib.c:51221)
  File "tslib.pyx", line 3565, in pandas.tslib.LocaleTime.__calc_weekday (pandas\tslib.c:51571)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'day_abbr'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\z083423\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 380, in main
    prepare(preparation_data)
  File "C:\Users\z083423\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 495, in prepare
    '__parents_main__', file, path_name, etc
  File "G:\Stress Test\PPNR Models\Model_Management_App\Model_Mgnt_Proj\ModelMgntMainDeleteThis.py", line 5, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "C:\Users\z083423\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import hashtable, tslib, lib
  File "tslib.pyx", line 3744, in init pandas.tslib (pandas\tslib.c:66221)
  File "tslib.pyx", line 3662, in pandas.tslib.TimeRE.__init__ (pandas\tslib.c:53412)
  File "tslib.pyx", line 3545, in pandas.tslib.LocaleTime.__init__ (pandas\tslib.c:51221)
  File "tslib.pyx", line 3565, in pandas.tslib.LocaleTime.__calc_weekday (pandas\tslib.c:51571)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'day_abbr'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\z083423\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 380, in main
    prepare(preparation_data)
  File "C:\Users\z083423\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 495, in prepare
    '__parents_main__', file, path_name, etc
  File "G:\Stress Test\PPNR Models\Model_Management_App\Model_Mgnt_Proj\ModelMgntMainDeleteThis.py", line 5, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "C:\Users\z083423\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import hashtable, tslib, lib
  File "tslib.pyx", line 3744, in init pandas.tslib (pandas\tslib.c:66221)
  File "tslib.pyx", line 3662, in pandas.tslib.TimeRE.__init__ (pandas\tslib.c:53412)
  File "tslib.pyx", line 3545, in pandas.tslib.LocaleTime.__init__ (pandas\tslib.c:51221)
  File "tslib.pyx", line 3565, in pandas.tslib.LocaleTime.__calc_weekday (pandas\tslib.c:51571)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'day_abbr'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\z083423\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 380, in main
    prepare(preparation_data)
  File "C:\Users\z083423\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 495, in prepare
    '__parents_main__', file, path_name, etc
  File "G:\Stress Test\PPNR Models\Model_Management_App\Model_Mgnt_Proj\ModelMgntMainDeleteThis.py", line 5, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "C:\Users\z083423\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import hashtable, tslib, lib
  File "tslib.pyx", line 3744, in init pandas.tslib (pandas\tslib.c:66221)
  File "tslib.pyx", line 3662, in pandas.tslib.TimeRE.__init__ (pandas\tslib.c:53412)
  File "tslib.pyx", line 3545, in pandas.tslib.LocaleTime.__init__ (pandas\tslib.c:51221)
  File "tslib.pyx", line 3565, in pandas.tslib.LocaleTime.__calc_weekday (pandas\tslib.c:51571)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'day_abbr'
'module' object has no attribute 'day_abbr'
'module' object has no attribute 'day_abbr'
'module' object has no attribute 'day_abbr'
'module' object has no attribute 'day_abbr'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\z083423\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 380, in main
    prepare(preparation_data)
  File "C:\Users\z083423\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 495, in prepare
    '__parents_main__', file, path_name, etc
  File "G:\Stress Test\PPNR Models\Model_Management_App\Model_Mgnt_Proj\ModelMgntMainDeleteThis.py", line 5, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "C:\Users\z083423\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import hashtable, tslib, lib
  File "tslib.pyx", line 3744, in init pandas.tslib (pandas\tslib.c:66221)
  File "tslib.pyx", line 3662, in pandas.tslib.TimeRE.__init__ (pandas\tslib.c:53412)
  File "tslib.pyx", line 3545, in pandas.tslib.LocaleTime.__init__ (pandas\tslib.c:51221)
  File "tslib.pyx", line 3565, in pandas.tslib.LocaleTime.__calc_weekday (pandas\tslib.c:51571)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'day_abbr'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\z083423\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 380, in main
    prepare(preparation_data)
  File "C:\Users\z083423\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 495, in prepare
    '__parents_main__', file, path_name, etc
  File "G:\Stress Test\PPNR Models\Model_Management_App\Model_Mgnt_Proj\ModelMgntMainDeleteThis.py", line 5, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "C:\Users\z083423\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import hashtable, tslib, lib
  File "tslib.pyx", line 3744, in init pandas.tslib (pandas\tslib.c:66221)
  File "tslib.pyx", line 3662, in pandas.tslib.TimeRE.__init__ (pandas\tslib.c:53412)
  File "tslib.pyx", line 3545, in pandas.tslib.LocaleTime.__init__ (pandas\tslib.c:51221)
  File "tslib.pyx", line 3565, in pandas.tslib.LocaleTime.__calc_weekday (pandas\tslib.c:51571)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'day_abbr'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\z083423\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 380, in main
    prepare(preparation_data)
  File "C:\Users\z083423\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 495, in prepare
    '__parents_main__', file, path_name, etc
  File "G:\Stress Test\PPNR Models\Model_Management_App\Model_Mgnt_Proj\ModelMgntMainDeleteThis.py", line 5, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "C:\Users\z083423\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import hashtable, tslib, lib
  File "tslib.pyx", line 3744, in init pandas.tslib (pandas\tslib.c:66221)
  File "tslib.pyx", line 3662, in pandas.tslib.TimeRE.__init__ (pandas\tslib.c:53412)
  File "tslib.pyx", line 3545, in pandas.tslib.LocaleTime.__init__ (pandas\tslib.c:51221)
  File "tslib.pyx", line 3565, in pandas.tslib.LocaleTime.__calc_weekday (pandas\tslib.c:51571)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'day_abbr'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\z083423\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 380, in main
    prepare(preparation_data)
  File "C:\Users\z083423\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 495, in prepare
    '__parents_main__', file, path_name, etc
  File "G:\Stress Test\PPNR Models\Model_Management_App\Model_Mgnt_Proj\ModelMgntMainDeleteThis.py", line 5, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "C:\Users\z083423\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import hashtable, tslib, lib
  File "tslib.pyx", line 3744, in init pandas.tslib (pandas\tslib.c:66221)
  File "tslib.pyx", line 3662, in pandas.tslib.TimeRE.__init__ (pandas\tslib.c:53412)
  File "tslib.pyx", line 3545, in pandas.tslib.LocaleTime.__init__ (pandas\tslib.c:51221)
  File "tslib.pyx", line 3565, in pandas.tslib.LocaleTime.__calc_weekday (pandas\tslib.c:51571)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'day_abbr'
'module' object has no attribute 'day_abbr'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\z083423\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 380, in main
    prepare(preparation_data)
  File "C:\Users\z083423\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 495, in prepare
    '__parents_main__', file, path_name, etc
  File "G:\Stress Test\PPNR Models\Model_Management_App\Model_Mgnt_Proj\ModelMgntMainDeleteThis.py", line 5, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "C:\Users\z083423\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import hashtable, tslib, lib
  File "tslib.pyx", line 3744, in init pandas.tslib (pandas\tslib.c:66221)
  File "tslib.pyx", line 3662, in pandas.tslib.TimeRE.__init__ (pandas\tslib.c:53412)
  File "tslib.pyx", line 3545, in pandas.tslib.LocaleTime.__init__ (pandas\tslib.c:51221)
  File "tslib.pyx", line 3565, in pandas.tslib.LocaleTime.__calc_weekday (pandas\tslib.c:51571)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'day_abbr'
```

From everything I've read is may be a namespace error where I'm importing modules that have attributes that share the same name. I have narrowed it down to my import of the pandas and multiprocessing modules (i.e. if I do it with one, but not the other it works fine). There are many examples online that successfully import both these modules. I can run these examples; however, when I try to do something custom, I can't get it to work. I'm sure I'm missing something. Below is an example of some code that gives me the error. Any help would be very appreciated!

```
import wx
import time

import sys

import pandas as pd
import multiprocessing as mp

def Worker():
    time.sleep(3)
    return [(1,2),(2,3),(4,5)]

class TheApp(wx.App):
     def OnInit(self):
         mainFrame = MainFrame(None, 'Test')
         mainFrame.Show()
         return True

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, theParent, theTitle):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent=theParent, title=theTitle, size=(200,200))
        self.Centre()
        myPanel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.myLabel = wx.StaticText(myPanel, -1, label="Start")

        pool = mp.Pool(4)
        pool.apply_async(func=Worker, callback=self.CallBackFunc)       

        #self.CallBackFunc([(1,2),(2,3),(4,5)])

    def CallBackFunc(self, returnValue):
        reader = pd.DataFrame.from_records(returnValue)
        self.myLabel.SetLabel(str(reader.get_value(1,1,True)))
        self.Refresh()           

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = TheApp(False)
    app.MainLoop()
    sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: Could you post the full traceback, rather than just the last line?

Comment: Added the full traceback.

Comment: I have the same issue. Import pandas gives this error: AttributeError: module 'calendar' has no attribute 'day_abbr'